# Fill graph sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory

I have got not increasing degree sequence:

$6,x,4,4,4,4,3,2$.

And I have task, fill the sequence so that the sequence of some graph.

Please can you hint me, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evenly many vertices have an odd degree.

> Since only one other number, 3, is odd, your $x$ must be odd also. So it must be 5.